# Открытие/сохранение файлов в графическом редакторе через диалоговое окно

Tags: c++

Написал на С++ простой графический редактор. Но не знаю, как сделать открытие и сохранение файлов через диалоговое окно, как это сделано в том же фотошопе. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Через winapi `#include <windows.h>` и вперед

Comment: Или самому написать, что более муторно

Comment: Зависит от того, что за библиотеку вы используете для графического интерфейса, в какой ОС и есть ли у вас какие-нибудь дополнительный требования к этому диалоговому окну. Стоит уточнить.